# Create Apache Camel Component for 3rd-Party REST API?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I'm in the process of getting familiar with Apache Camel.  I've got the basics of routing down, and now I'd like to investigate creating my own `Component` to leverage in a new project I'm working on.

There is a 3rd party commercial SaaS product that we use, and they provide both a RESTful API, as well as a Java-based SDK (that essentially wraps the REST API).  Given this scenario, what is the best way of accomplishing this?  Is it to create a new `Component`/`Endpoint`/`Producer`/`Consumer` classes that leverage the service's Java SDK to make these calls?  Is there a quicker way that would allow me to use Camel's underlying REST `Component`?

The goal here isn't just to get the integration piece working.  It's also for me to learn a bit more about Camel best-practices and creating my own `Component`s, as that will become a greater need as we move forward with integrating Camel into our environment.

Comment: Apache Camel already has it's own [REST client implementation](http://camel.apache.org/rest.html). So looks like all you need is just use it if you really have 3rd party RESTful API doc.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  As I stated in the question, however, the real goal is to learn the best way to develop custom Camel Components.  This integration may be a RESTful service, but others will not be.

Comment: Your main question is "what is the best way to accomplish this", and this answere is maybe to reuse existing components ;-) If you want to learn how to create a component - then it's offtopic on SO - You should probably read "camel in action", or the large libraries of component in the sources

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but I think it's worth mentioning another answer here (I was asking myself the same question not too long ago). It might be useful for someone else.

I've recently used the [camel-api-component-maven-plugin](http://planet.jboss.org/post/apache_camel_api_component_framework_or_how_i_learned_to_stop_worrying_and_love_writing_feature_rich_camel_components) to implement a [new Camel FHIR Component](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12625) that uses the HAPI-FHIR [sdk](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir) behind the scenes.

I think it's a great tool. It will generate boilerplate code that will integrate the 3rd party SDK with Camel. You just have to add the relevant SDK calls. It even generates test classes for you. It's used by other Components like Box, some Google Components, AS2, Olingo to name a few. The tool helps to keep these homogeneous in the way their implemented/tested.

HTH

John.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other commenters. Use the existing REST component. That is the whole point of using REST/SOAP is that there is a standard for communicating to remote systems. You'll then have more control over how to handle the payloads.. as text JSON/XML or convert to Java POJO's as well.

In the ESB v1 era 2000-2005 the rage was all about having components per API-- it ends up being a maintenance nightmare-- stay lightweight and you'll be a lot happier in the long run =)

Comment: Box, PayPal, Amazon AWS, etc.  There are custom components for all of those RESTful services, even though there is a REST component.  This is the same idea.  There is enough complexity to the service we'd be calling that I'd like to create my own component.

Answer (score 0):

Why create your own component if you want to connect to a standard REST API? Camel already has components for this for you to reuse and it is better to that. Create new components only when you deal with new data formats, new systems or protocols.

Comment: Box, PayPal, Amazon AWS, etc.  There are custom components for all of those RESTful services, even though there is a REST component.  This is the same idea.  There is enough complexity to the service we'd be calling that I'd like to create my own component.